# ERROR: '::main' must return 'int'

Tags: c++

This my main function:

```
void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc >= 4)
    {
        ProcessScheduler *processScheduler;
        std::cout <<
            "Running algorithm: " << argv[2] <<
            "\nWith a CSP of: " << argv[3] <<
            "\nFilename: " << argv[1] <<
            std::endl << std::endl;

        if (argc == 4)
        {
            processScheduler = new ProcessScheduler(
                argv[2],
                atoi(argv[3])
            );
        }
        else
        {
            processScheduler = new ProcessScheduler(
                argv[2],
                atoi(argv[3]),
                atoi(argv[4]),
                atoi(argv[5])
            );
        }
        processScheduler -> LoadFile(argv[1]);
        processScheduler -> RunProcesses();

        GanntChart ganntChart(*processScheduler);
        ganntChart.DisplayChart();
        ganntChart.DisplayTable();
        ganntChart.DisplaySummary();

        system("pause");

        delete processScheduler;
    }
    else
    {
        PrintUsage();
    }
}
```

The error I get when I compile is this:

> Application.cpp:41:32: error: '::main' must return 'int'

It's a void function how can I return int and how do I fix it?

Comment: Change the signature to `int`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3652182/10077

Comment: What's unclear about that error message for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Code goes here

    return 0;
}
```

The `return 0;` returns a 0 to the operating system which means that the program executed successfully.

Comment: The `return 0;` is implied in C++, and unnecessary.

Comment: Yes I agree. It is there for convention and is good practice to include so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to have void main and return nothing but I guess it has to be int. after changing void to int that did solve the error

Comment: @Michael this is not the solution.

Comment: @roottraveller can you provide some insight as to why it isn't?

Answer (score 7):

C++ requires `main()` to be of type `int`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. I thought you could have void main

Comment: @Nick Pavini, do you have any documentation? please share with us.

Comment: conflict to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890848/can-main-function-return-double

Answer (score 1):

Function is declared as `int main(..);`, so change your `void` return value to `int`, and `return 0` at the end of the main function.